# several walkers walking on a grid: How to organize the threads?

Tags: multithreading

My algorithm is processing DEMs. a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) is a representations of ground topography where elevation is known at grid nodes.

My problem can be summarized as follows:
Q is a queue containing nodes to visit.
at start, the boundary of the grid is pushed in Q.

```
while Q is not empty, do 
   remove Node N from the top of Q
   if N was never visited then do 
      consider the 8 neighbors of N
      among them select the unvisited ones
      among them select those with a higher elevation than N's
      push these at Q's tail
      mark N as visited
  done
done
```

As described, the algorithm will mark as 'visited' every node that can be reached from the border by a continuously ascendant path. It is worth noticing that the order of processing the nodes in the queue is unimportant. Note also that some points may request a tortuous ascendant path to be reached from the border. Think for example to a cone with a furrow spiraling around it. The ridge of the furrow is such a unique and tortuous path capable of reaching the top of the cone without never descending into the furrow.

Anyway, I want to mutithread this algorithm. I am still in the first step of wondering which is the best organization of data and threads in order to have as least pain as possible at debugging the beast when it is written.

My first thought is to divide the grid into tiles and split the Queue in as many tiles as there is in the grid. The tiles are piled in a work-list. A few threads are parsing the work-list and grab any tile where something can be done at the moment.

Working on a specific tile will firstly need that the tile's queue is not empty. I may also need that the neighboring tiles can be locked if the walker's tile has to visit a node at the edge of the tile.

I am thinking that when a walker cannot lock a neighboring tile while it needs to, then it can skip to the next node in the local queue, or even the thread itself can release the tile to the work-list and seek for another tile to work on.

My actual experience of multi-thread programming is good enough to understand that this lovely description is very likely to turn into a nightmare when I will debug it. However I am not experienced enough to evaluate the various possibilities of programming the algorithm and make a good decision, having in mind that I will not be given a month to debug a spaghetti dish.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: interesting :) has it been solved yet?